# How to use ajax to link views to form? Django

Tags: django, ajax

views.py

```
def contact_form(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = {
                'success': True,
            }
            status = 200
        else:
            data = {
                'success': False,
                'errors': form.errors.get_json_data(),
            }
            status = 400
        return JsonResponse(data, status=status)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("django.contrib.staticfiles.urls")),
    path("single-post/", single_post, name="single-post"),
    path("contact-form/", contact_form, name="contact-form"),
    path("", index),
]
```

index.html

```
<form id="contactForm" method="get" action="{% url 'contact-form' %}">                  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" name="subject">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit my form I get:
**The view app.views.contact_form didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

How do I use ajax to link the form to contact_form?

Comment: Where is your javascript that is submitting the AJAX request? If you submit normally a form it will not be an AJAX request

Comment: If `contact_form` code above is full, I'd guess it's not entering `if request.is_ajax():`, and returning `None` as such.  Try printing `request.is_ajax()` before the `if` to confirm